# Red Hat Linux: default route not persistent

Tags: rhel, route

My default route disappears from the routing table on network restart or system reboot.

The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network` are:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=server
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
GATEWAY=192.1.1.250
GATEWAYDEV=Wired_connection_1
```

The contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-Wired_connection_1` are:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
GATEWAY0=192.1.1.250
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="Wired connection 1"
UUID=4aef50a9-b5fe-4b60-abe9-e7de5d4c194e
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICE=Wired_connection_1
USERCTL=no
HWADDR=2C:27:D7:33:6D:9E
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
```

Any suggestions how do I make my default route persistent?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add this line to the adapter-specific ifcfg (Interface configuration) file under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` directory.

```
default via ip_address hardware_interface_name
```

Comment: Did you mean `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface configuration>` instead? As far as I know, `ifcfg-*` files require a `VARIABLE="value"` syntax on all settings.

Comment: No, I meant ifcfg-*.  It's what worked for me.  Of course, this is a pretty old version of Red Hat (Fedora release 15).

Answer (score 0):

Create a static file with name of your adapter For Example if you have ens192 then give the name "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ens192"

and Add content like

```
IP_where_you_to_go/32 via Gateway src IP_of_your_interface
172.16.6.20/32 via 192.168.10.254 src 192.168.10.11
```

then restart NetworkManager or network service

Answer (score 0):

Which version of RHEL is that?

Specifying default gateway in `/etc/sysconfig/network` is the deprecated old, at least pre-RHEL 5.x style. And `GATEWAYDEV` expects a **device** name like `eth0` or `eno1`, not a NetworkManager **connection name** like `Wired_connection_1`. If you are using NetworkManager, you should have neither `GATEWAY` nor `GATEWAYDEV` defined in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

`GATEWAY0` is part of the old three-line route syntax used in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface>` files: to specify a default gateway in a `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` file, you use just `GATEWAY=` without a number.

And you have `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` which generally means the DHCP server would be expected to tell the system the default gateway. I'm not sure if NetworkManager even allows you to override a default gateway setting just like that: according to table 93 of [NetworkManager reference manual](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Elkundrak/nm-docs/ref-settings.html#id-1.4.3), NetworkManager will ignore the gateway setting if the IP address is not also set locally.

If you specifically need to *override* a DHCP-configured default gateway (or the DHCP server provides no default gateway at all) while still using NetworkManager, you might try creating file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-Wired_connection_1` with the following contents:

```
default via 192.1.1.250
```

In NetworkManager, that should get mapped to the `ipv4.routes` (or `route-data`, depending on NetworkManager version) property, which might also work together with DHCP (or at least, is *not documented not to work* when no IP address is assigned locally).